# How to mount an Android (2.3.4) device on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, usb, mount, android

Ubuntu recognizes the device, and seemingly assigned it to sdc in this instance, but mount keeps returning a 'no medium found' message. Here is `lsusb` output:

```
us 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04d9:1603 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0fce:215b Sony Ericsson Mobile Communications AB
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 058f:6362 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Card Reader/Writer
```

`dmesg| grep scsi` output:

```
[    0.568150] ACPI: bus type scsi registered
[    1.023975] scsi0 : ata_piix
[    1.024035] scsi1 : ata_piix
[    1.179932] scsi2 : ata_piix
[    1.179982] scsi3 : ata_piix
[    1.223582] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access  ATA  SAMSUNG SSD 830  CXM0 PQ: 0  ANSI: 5
[    1.223662] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[    1.224331] scsi 1:0:1:0: CD-ROM            HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GH24NS90  IN01 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    1.229146] sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 24x/48x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[    1.229218] sr 1:0:1:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[    1.229261] sr 1:0:1:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
[    1.424473] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      ST3000DM001-1CH1 CC24 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    1.424606] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[    1.489666] scsi4 : ahci
[    1.489714] scsi5 : ahci
[    4.121421] scsi6 : usb-storage 2-1.7:1.0
[    4.121493] scsi7 : usb-storage 2-1.8:1.0
[    5.120804] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  USB SD Reader    1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[    5.120832] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SEMC     Mass Storage     0100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[    5.121357] scsi 6:0:0:1: Direct-Access     Generic  USB CF Reader    1.01 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[    5.121577] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[    5.121859] scsi 6:0:0:2: Direct-Access     Generic  USB SM Reader    1.02 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[    5.122627] scsi 6:0:0:3: Direct-Access     Generic  USB MS Reader    1.03 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[    5.123620] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
[    5.123725] sd 6:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg5 type 0
[    5.123826] sd 6:0:0:2: Attached scsi generic sg6 type 0
[    5.125361] sd 6:0:0:3: Attached scsi generic sg7 type 0
[  821.206856] scsi8 : usb-storage 2-1.8:1.0
[  822.206192] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SEMC     Mass Storage     0100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  822.207363] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[ 1044.183578] scsi9 : usb-storage 2-1.5:1.0
[ 1045.183448] scsi 9:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SEMC     Mass Storage     0100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 1045.184785] sd 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
```

Also, here is `ls -laR /dev/disk` output:

```
/dev/disk/by-id:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 540 May 29 23:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 120 May 29 22:55 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 May 29 22:55 ata-HL-DT-ST_DVDRAM_GH24NS90_K61C7663112 ->     ../../sr0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 May 29 22:55 ata-SAMSUNG_SSD_830_Series_S0Z3NEAC844116 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 May 29 22:55 ata-SAMSUNG_SSD_830_Series_S0Z3NEAC844116-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 May 29 22:55 ata-SAMSUNG_SSD_830_Series_S0Z3NEAC844116-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 May 29 22:55 ata-SAMSUNG_SSD_830_Series_S0Z3NEAC844116- part5 -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 May 29 22:55 ata-ST3000DM001-1CH166_Z1F1HHH1 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 May 29 22:55 ata-ST3000DM001-1CH166_Z1F1HHH1-part1 ->  ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 May 29 22:55 scsi-SATA_SAMSUNG_SSD_830S0Z3NEAC844116 ->  ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 May 29 22:55 scsi-SATA_SAMSUNG_SSD_830S0Z3NEAC844116-part1   -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 May 29 22:55 scsi-SATA_SAMSUNG_SSD_830S0Z3NEAC844116-part2  -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 May 29 22:55 scsi-SATA_SAMSUNG_SSD_830S0Z3NEAC844116-part5  -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 May 29 22:55 scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-1CH_Z1F1HHH1 ->  ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 May 29 22:55 scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-1CH_Z1F1HHH1-part1 ->  ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 May 29 22:55 usb-Generic_USB_CF_Reader_058F312D81B-0:1 ->  ../../sde
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 May 29 22:55 usb-Generic_USB_MS_Reader_058F312D81B-0:3 ->  ../../sdg
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 May 29 22:55 usb-Generic_USB_SD_Reader_058F312D81B-0:0 -> ../../sdd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 May 29 22:55 usb-Generic_USB_SM_Reader_058F312D81B-0:2 -> ../../sdf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 May 29 23:12 usb-SEMC_Mass_Storage_43423541314545314A4D-0:0 -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 May 29 22:55 wwn-0x5000c5004ec935bc -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 May 29 22:55 wwn-0x5000c5004ec935bc-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 May 29 22:55 wwn-0x5001480000000000 -> ../../sr0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 May 29 22:55 wwn-0x5002538043584d30 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 May 29 22:55 wwn-0x5002538043584d30-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 May 29 22:55 wwn-0x5002538043584d30-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 May 29 22:55 wwn-0x5002538043584d30-part5 -> ../../sda5
```

and finally my `mount` call:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdc /mnt
mount: no medium found on /dev/sdc
```

I've rebooted several times and used all the available ports on my computer. The phone model Sony Ericsson. I've also created the udev rule:

`SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0fce", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"`.

The file is located at:

`/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`.
Am I being dumb and overlooking something obvious (sorry if I am...)?

Thanks for any help you can offer.

### Update

As this device isn't activated (no service provided from Verizon) I'm unable to update the software. After searching, it seems that 2.3.4 can't be rooted (so I can flash the newest firmware to the device) using the SuperOneClick program ( I really wanted to use this...). So I ended up downgrading the device to 2.3.3 by rooting it and flashing the 2.3.3 firmware to the device. After a reboot of the device, the phone asked me if I would like to mount my SD card, which I did, and Ubuntu recognized it correctly. So I'm now able to continue my original project, but the original question of how to mount the SD card of this device running 2.3.4 is still unanswered... So to anyone else that has a Sony Ericsson Xperia Play running 2.3.4 trying to mount the SD card (without taking the card out and putting in an SD card reader...), I'd recommend downgrading (or upgrading...) the device until an actual solution is found. Root at your own risk!

Answer (score 2):

You can't mount an Android device in the normal way like an flash drive.

You have to use MTP (Media Transfer Protocol) - a protocol for intelligent storage devices. There is a FUSE filesystem called [mtpfs [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/mtpfs/) that you can use it in this sense. See here more information: [Mounting your MTP Android’s SD Card on Ubuntu](http://www.mysolutions.it/mounting-your-mtp-androids-sd-card-on-ubuntu/).

Also I found this thread about [How to properly mount Android 4.0+ devices in Ubuntu using Go-MTPFS](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/how-to-mount-android-40-ubuntu-go-mtpfs.html) that can be helpful. The idea in this tread is about using [Go-mtpfs](https://github.com/hanwen/go-mtpfs).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! As I understood it, android started using MTP in honeycomb (3.0) and my device is running gingerbread (2.3.4). I was under the impression that androids running software less than honeycomb were using UMS transfer system so I thought using the MTP was uncalled for in my case. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @user138283 Just give it a try to [Mounting your MTP Android’s SD Card on Ubuntu](http://www.mysolutions.it/mounting-your-mtp-androids-sd-card-on-ubuntu/). Nothing to lose.

Comment: Following the tutorial on the link you sent and searching on my own, I made it this far... 

    `sudo mtpfs -o allow_other /mnt/Android_Device
    Unable to open ~/.mtpz-data for reading, MTPZ     disabled.Listing raw device(s)
    No raw devices found.`

Comment: @Kirk Why do you use `/mnt/Android_Device`? In that tutorial it says clear: `/media/MTPdevice`.