# How to mount an Android Device on i3?

Tags: usb, mount, android

I am using `i3` windows manager on Ubuntu 14.04. When I do `lsusb` I see:

```
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9100 Phone [Galaxy S II], GT-I9300 Phone [Galaxy S III], GT-P7500 [Galaxy Tab 10.1]
```

When I try `adb device -l` I don't see anything.

`Unity` automatically mounts my android devices, but `i3` doesn't.

I see some solution ideas [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/how-to-mount-android-40-ubuntu-go-mtpfs.html) and [here](http://www.mysolutions.it/mounting-your-mtp-androids-sd-card-on-ubuntu/). Both require me to install new things. Since `Unity` could mount my devices by itself, I wonder if I really need to install anything new. May be there is a more natural solution. And I am already using `udisk-glue` to auto-mount my external HD.

So question is:
How do I mount my android device without having to install too many new things, given that I already have `Unity` and `udisk-glue`

Here is a [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/301843/how-to-mount-an-android-2-3-4-device-on-ubuntu-13-04).

EDIT:
I tried the above anyways. Here are issues:
1. [Go-mtps](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/how-to-mount-android-40-ubuntu-go-mtpfs.html) is available only till Ubuntu 12.04. I can't install it on 14.04. 2. I am unable to find my `idVendor` and `idProduct` as instructed [here](http://www.mysolutions.it/mounting-your-mtp-androids-sd-card-on-ubuntu/) because what the hell is `mtp-detect`? `mtp-detect` is not available on 14.04! And since I intend to be mounting my phone on `i3` I suspect the USB system handler will be different from what is given in the instructions. I would still need help! Lot of help! Please help!

Comment: `adb` and `mtp` are two different things. What protocol you want to use? From your explanations i think you want `mtp`. i3 does not do automounting, so you have to do it by yourself. Last time i used http://www.adebenham.com/mtpfs/ maybe that works for you?

Answer (score 0):

**update Cifs**  then mount the device before enable mass storage in your mobile / Android device.

after use cifs command its will work. for more `man cifs`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Could you please elaborate more?